# Java - Is ArrayList<Integer>[][] possible?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer>[][] matrix = new ArrayList<Integer]>[sizeX][sizeY]();
```

or

```
ArrayList<Integer>[][] matrix = new ArrayList<Integer]>()[sizeX][sizeY];
```

don't work, I'm starting to think that it's not even possible to store ArrayLists in a matrix?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The two things you posted are clearly not possible, as they don't compile. Could you tell us what you *want*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you still want to use and array:

```
    ArrayList<Integer>[][] matrix = new ArrayList[1][1];
    matrix[0][0]=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //matrix[0][0].add(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<List<Integer>> twoDList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Read more on [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to create a multidimensional array (matrix) where I have an ArrayList on each position.

Comment: Hard to be sure, but it sounds like the OP actually wants a 3d matrix: a 2d matrix whose cells are arraylists.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

It means that you list will be consisting of List of Integers as its value.

Answer (score 0):

Generics and arrays generally don't mix well, but this will work (gives a warning, which can be safely ignored):

```
ArrayList<Integer>[][] matrix = new ArrayList[sizeX][sizeY];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a list in an array then you still have to separate the declaration and the inizialization:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[][] matrix = new ArrayList[10][10];
```

will specify a 2-dim-array of ArrayList objects.

```
matrix[0][0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

will initialize one specific cell with a new ArrayList of Integers.